# Android: cannot focus anything in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus, android-framelayout

I'm creating a `FragmentActivity`.
The xml file related to this `Activity` is a `FrameLayout`.

When i'm inflating my `FrameLayout`, i've got differents views in it like `Spinners`, `EditTexts`, `Buttons` ...

But I cannot focus on touch any of them.

The spinners are not displaying their lists, the buttons are not performing `clickListener` etc...

I already tried to force focus to a particular widget and it's working but, for example, when I force the focus to the `EditText` the virtual keyboard is not showing. I really don't understand.

Comment: did u set onClick LIsteners??

Comment: Try to change FrgmentActivity to AppcompatActivity

Comment: Yes, I already set OnClickListener @DemoMail

Comment: @KhizarHayat, can you explain why?

Comment: First try and tell if its work

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

so the answer wasn't due to the `FrameLayout` or the `FragmentActivity`.

In my `FrameLayout`, I have a `DrawerLayout` with a match_parent height attribute.
When I set the height to this Drawer, even if it still empty, it goes to the front of my view, keepng the focus on it but because it's empty, it's like a transparent layout above the whole view preventing all the click for the views below.

Btw thank you for your time ! :)